# SimpleXMLElement and getting attribute value?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am having trouble getting all the data from my XML. Can any one shed some light please.

My XML is as follows

```
<storeitems>
<PRODUCT ITEM="3002074730">
<SPECIALS_ID>14713</SPECIALS_ID>
<FULL_PRICE>27.00</FULL_PRICE>
<SPECIALS_NEW_PRODUCTS_PRICE>25.65</SPECIALS_NEW_PRODUCTS_PRICE>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM="SE-0088-10-3">
<SPECIALS_ID>29555</SPECIALS_ID>
<FULL_PRICE>53.99</FULL_PRICE>
<SPECIALS_NEW_PRODUCTS_PRICE>51.29</SPECIALS_NEW_PRODUCTS_PRICE>
</PRODUCT>
<storeitems>
```

My code is as follows

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

foreach($xml->PRODUCT as $post) {

    echo $post->SPECIALS_ID .'<BR>';
    echo $post->FULL_PRICE . '<BR>';
    echo $post->SPECIALS_NEW_PRODUCTS_PRICE . '<BR>';
}
```

This does what I expect but can you assist me in getting this part of the XML to echo please

```
<PRODUCT ITEM="3002074730">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $post->attributes();
```

will print the value of your `item` (first) attribute (it's an object that does that when it's called in a string-context).

If you add more attributes and you want to get them all, you can iterate over [`$post->attributes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php):

```
foreach($post->attributes() as $name => $value){
  ...
}
```